# PhpMyAdmin Error on index page : Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm new on StackOverflow, and i've to admit i'm not here out of courtesy ^^

Here is my problem :

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04; i did install phpmyadmin and mysql but i've got that notice on the index page of my phpmyadmin interface, and i'm simply tring to access my databases :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOHVP.png

The notices are :

```
./libraries/common.inc.php#178: PhpMyAdmin\Core::checkTokenRequestParam()
./index.php#15: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

and

```
Notice in ./libraries/classes/Core.php#1323
Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD
```

When i try to register, it will merely loop on the index page, even though my ids are good; and clicking the "Rapporter" (Report) or "Ignorer tout" (Ignore all) button loads forever with the loading yellow band

I've already tried :

- Reinstalling phpmyadmin and mysql via the official Ubuntu repos
- Reinstalling phpmyadmin manually
- Checked `systemctl status apache2`; status is okay
- Trying to debug the problem of my own following what it says (in vain)...

I have no clue on what it could be that i did wrong, any help is welcome, Thanks :)

Comment: You should raise the question on phpmyadmin's support forum as this is a potential bug in their product!

Comment: Okey, i'll do that 
(You're my first answer on Stack Overflow :-))

Comment: It was just a comment, not a proper answer :)

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16991